# When is it best to use object_setInstanceVariable OR object_setIvar in the Objective-C Runtime?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

When is it best to use one or the other?

***object_setInstanceVariable***
Changes the value of an instance variable of a class instance.

**Ivar object_setInstanceVariable(id obj, const char *name, void *value)**
Parameters
obj
A pointer to an instance of a class. Pass the object containing the instance variable whose value you wish to modify.
name
A C string. Pass the name of the instance variable whose value you wish to modify.
value
The new value for the instance variable.
Return Value
A pointer to the Ivar data structure that defines the type and name of the instance variable specified by name.

Availability
Available in OS X v10.0 and later.
Declared In
objc/runtime.h

***object_setIvar***
Sets the value of an instance variable in an object.

**void object_setIvar(id object, Ivar ivar, id value)**
Parameters
object
The object containing the instance variable whose value you want to set.
ivar
The Ivar describing the instance variable whose value you want to set.
value
The new value for the instance variable.
Discussion
object_setIvar is faster than object_setInstanceVariable if the Ivar for the instance variable is already known.

Availability
Available in OS X v10.5 and later.
Declared In
objc/runtime.h

Comment: Isn't the answer right there? "object_setIvar is faster than object_setInstanceVariable if the Ivar for the instance variable is already known."

Comment: Modified the question, as I meant to ask something else. What do you mean by faster? Faster to use, as in convenient, or faster in code, as in the time it takes to execute?

Comment: Could be both, but the motivation for adding the new method was almost certainly the latter. If the caller does some work up front (looking up the Ivar) then repeated calls to `object_setIvar` would be faster to execute.

Comment: So they are both the same essentially. Just that the slower one gets a name for the ivar and then probably does some listing and searching to find it while the second one get a pointer to the Ivar directly?

Comment: Yes. In fact if you read [the source code](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-551.1/runtime/objc-class.mm) it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Wow great. Please add this as an answer with a small explanation of how they are different and I will accept it! Thanks again!

Comment: object_setInstanceVariable is unavailable when compiling with ARC.